# Why are subdocuments possibly undefined in Mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, types

Given a subdocument within a Mongoose schema:

```
const someSchema = new Schema(
  {
    sub: {
      val: { type: String, default: "" },
    },

    // other properties ...
  }
);
```

The type of sub shown by TypeScript is:

```
(property) sub?: {
    val: string;
} | null | undefined
```

This becomes a problem when inferring the type of the parent document using Mongoose's `InferSchemaType` Utility:

```
type Doc = InferSchemaType<typeof someSchema>
//   ^? type Doc = {
//  sub?: {
//      val: string;
//  } | null | undefined;
```

**How can I ensure that `sub` is not possibly `null` or `undefined`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

> Mongoose applies defaults recursively, which means there's a nice workaround if you want to make sure Mongoose applies subdocument defaults: make the subdocument path default to an empty object.

To ensure that the `sub` subdocument is not `null` or `undefined`, move the current children inside a `type` property, and apply a default empty object to the subdocument like so:

```
const someSchema = new Schema(
  {
    sub: {
      default: () => ({}),
      type: {
        val: { type: String, default: "" },
      }
    },

    // other properties ...
  }
);
```

**This will result in the following `Doc` type:**

```
type Doc = InferSchemaType<typeof someSchema>
//   ^? type Doc = {
//  sub: {
//      val: string;
//  };
```